# Return as String Value from For Loop Java

Tags: java, string, loops

I'm trying to create a loop of 50 characters and then return the whole 50 characters as a String, but unfortunately the String is only returning the last letter, and not all 50 characters. getRandomUpperChar() is just a method I created to get a random Uppercase char value from 'A' to 'Z'.

```
public static String initializeKey(int num , int minNum, int maxNum) {
    String random = "";
    for(int j = 0; j <num; j++) {
        getRandomUpperChar();
        char Xp = getRandomUpperChar(minNum, maxNum);

        random = "" +  Xp;
        System.out.print(random);
    }
    return random;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the method call to `getRandomUpperChar()` with no args doing on line 4?  Is your method overloaded?  If so, what does the no-arg method do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something very basic

```
random+= "" +Xp
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you so much kind sir.

Comment: You can also write `random += Xp;`. Looks much cleaner and it works, due to the correct `random` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, replacing

```
random = "" +  Xp;
```

with

```
random = random +  Xp;
```

would make it work, but a better solution would be:

```
public static String initializeKey(int num, int minNum, int maxNum) {
  StringBuilder random = new StringBuilder();

  for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
     char xp = getRandomUpperChar(minNum, maxNum);
     random.append(xp);
  }

  return random.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: string concatenation (random = random + xp) allocates at least 2 new Strings each time you do it, which tends to thrash the garbage collector. The method shown above allocates one StringBuilder and one String, and is _much_ preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your

```
random = "" +  Xp;
```

with

```
random +="" + Xp;
```

and you would be fine.

Comment: Thank you as well mattias! I knew it must be something simple, but I couldn't of the life of me figure it out!! Thank you!!

Comment: A tip for the future is to debug your code, when you run into problems like this one. Then you would easily spot where the problem is.